# How to remove/replace a specific text in pdf, If the text to replace is drawn using multiple instructions following each other?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox, itext7

I've tried the following code. It works fine, but only for limited cases like if the text is added with a single instruction. How to do this if the text is added in multiple instructions. Can anyone help me out with this?

````
for (PDPage page : document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages()) {
    PdfContentStreamEditor editor = new PdfContentStreamEditor(document, page) {
        final StringBuilder recentChars = new StringBuilder();
        @Override
        protected void showGlyph(Matrix textRenderingMatrix, PDFont font, int code, Vector displacement)
                throws IOException {
            String string = font.toUnicode(code);
            if (string != null)
                recentChars.append(string);

            super.showGlyph(textRenderingMatrix, font, code, displacement);
        }

        @Override
        protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter, Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
            String recentText = recentChars.toString();
            recentChars.setLength(0);
            String operatorString = operator.getName();

            if (TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS.contains(operatorString) && "Text which is to be replace".equals(recentText))
            {
                return;
            }

            super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);
        }

        final List<String> TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList("Tj", "'", "\"", "TJ");
    };
    editor.processPage(page);
}
document.save("watermark-RemoveByText.pdf");```
````

Comment: Hmmm, removing a watermark doesn't sound very legitimate.. Besides, it's tough for us to give you code for how to match something if we don't really have examples of what needs to be matched and don't know what you're after in the PDF.

Comment: @xtralic, If there are Texts like this regex - "{{This text should be removed}}" , if I try to remove this text using the code I've mentioned, Only the "{{T" is stored in recentChars and then "his text should be rem" in the next recentChars array and finally "oved}}" is coming. So if I want to search a text using the regex, I can't replace/remove the text I've explained here. Did you understand my question?

Comment: @KJ I'm not talking about watermarks here, I just want to remove some text which matches some regex, But since whole text is not getting recognized at once, I'm stuck how to go further. Awaiting your reply!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use pdfSweep (iText 7 add-on) that removes or redacts information from a PDF document.
For more information see https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdf-redaction-pdfsweep

The code which removes "Text which is to be replace" text from PDF document on Java with using of PdfSweep looks like this:

```
try (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("Path to source file"), new PdfWriter("Path to out file"))) {
    ICleanupStrategy cleanupStrategy = new RegexBasedCleanupStrategy("Text which is to be replace")
        .setRedactionColor(ColorConstants.WHITE);
    PdfCleaner.autoSweepCleanUp(pdf, cleanupStrategy);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that but is there no way to remove it. If we use PdfSweep it only looks good for pdfs with white background, but for other colors it looks odd...

Comment: You can define color which will be used for filling. But unfortunately PdfSweep doesn't support removing text with background saving. You can create a custom cleanup strategy, which will understand which color is used in current location and fill by the necessary color. But this approach is hard to implement because there are a lot of different cases how background can set.

Comment: then, How to get the background color of a pdf at a certain position or area?

Comment: @AkhilNagaSai i think that it is other question. Because there is no simple answer on it.